# Conservation of mechanical energy isn't giving me the right answer?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, momentum

I have been trying to solve this question:

You are working for a shipping company. Your job is to stand at the bottom of an 8.0 m long ramp that is inclined at 37 degrees above the
horizontal. You grab packages off a conveyor belt and propel them up the ramp. The coefficient of kinetic friction between the packages and the
ramp is 0.30. (a) What speed do you need to give a package at the bottom of the ramp so that it has zero speed at the top of the ramp?

Here is my work

$W_{nc}= KE_{f}-KE_{i}+PE_{f}-PE_{i}$

$μF_{n}d= -\frac{mv^{2}}{2} +mgh$

$μmgcosϴd= -\frac{mv^{2}}{2} +mgdsinϴ$

After plugging in the numbers and solving for initial velocity I got v = 7.54 m/s. The answer for initial velocity is supposed to be around 11 m/s. I'm not sure why I'm not getting the right answer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Mechanical energy is not conserved when there is a friction so you cannot use this method. You can verify it in simpler case: Suppose you pushed the package on a flat surface - its potential energy does not change, yet the package will lose kinetic energy as it will stop due to friction. Mechanical energy is not conserved - some/all of it will escape the system as heat.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct except for one sign, note that the work done by friction is negative (since you move the block in the opposite direction w.r.t. the friction force) and thus it is equal to
$$ -\mu mg d \cos \theta $$

with this solving for $ v$ gives you 11.49 m/s.